# Can Hypnotic Gaze be used through Resilient Sphere?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard

Can the Enchantment Wizard's level 2 ability Hypnotic Gaze be used through a Resilient Sphere?

The ability seems to only required the Wizard to see the target, and the target to see or hear the Wizard:

> ... choose one creature that you can see within 5 feet of you. If the target can see or hear you...

I assume Resilient Sphere doesn't block vision or sound, but it definitely obstructs the path from the Wizard to the target. In addition, it is written that

> Nothing, not physical Objects, energy, or other spell Effects, can pass through the barrier

So, does the Hypnotic Gaze go through the Sphere or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Hypnotic Gaze is not a spell

The rules for targeting spells do not apply to things that aren’t spells, so you don’t need a clear path.

### However, ...

> **Nothing** can pass through the barrier

Hypnotic Gaze is **not** nothing even if it’s not a spell so it can’t pass through the sphere.

As an aside, “shimmering force” may or may not be transparent.

Comment: Abilities do what they say they do. Hypnotic gaze never says that it requires anything to pass between the wizard and target (other than line of sight), so nothing does. Whether the transmission of the ability counts as "energy" isn't relevant, because that energy need not necessarily pass through physical space. For example, the sphere doesn't block planar travel or teleportation, either.

Answer (score 4):

### You can't see through the sphere.

> Nothing--not physical objects, energy, or other spell effects--can pass through the barrier, in or out...

This includes light, so the creature can't see its surroundings.

Comment: This is almost certainly not RAI, but it seems correct.

Comment: @Iguanodon The only evidence it's _not_ intended is that the creature in the sphere can hamster-ball the sphere around from inside, which would be pretty useless if they couldn't see anything. But "Nothing--not [] energy" clearly rules out both light and sound, and we can contrast _wall of force_ and _forcecage_ which specify that the barriers are invisible.

Comment: Agreed. Though, in previous editions of D&D, the spell lacked the "energy" clause, so the spell may have been transparent. Plus, all of the art I can find of this spell online (though there doesn't seem to be anything official for 5e) depicts a transparent sphere, so if indeed the sphere is transparent, that's likely not how people are playing it.

Comment: @Iguanodon Even if the spell didn't mention "energy", it still says "nothing", and light is something.